# Failed to upload a file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, custom-wordpress-pages, fine-uploader

I've got trouble uploading a file, this code below should echo something in any case right ? but after submitting the form i don't get any message echoed, though the mail is sent. Can anyone help me with this problem ?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
            
                        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
                        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
                        if ( $movefile ) {
                            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                            var_dump($movefile);
                        } else {
                            echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
                        }
                    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
            #$hasError = true;
    }
```

> **UPDATE**
> i've changed the code a little bit, how it goes as follow:

```
if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
{ 
     require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}
    
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['attachments'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
$attachments = $movefile;
if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        #var_dump($movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
```

**but i get this error instead**

> File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Could not access file: File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.'

**What i've tried to solve this issue**

- changing upload limit didn't help (i can only do this at cpanel and those settings are configured by admin of the server)
- uploading an additional php.ini file to increase limits didn't help either

Comment: can you check the php5.ini file for upload and post size limits? Do check by uploading a small file once.

Comment: @Neo i've just sent 1.12 KB file and still i don't get any message

Comment: @Neo i don't think that the size of the uploaded file is the problem, because when i add a post with image, any image is posted, even the large ones

Comment: @Neo can you check the update pls ?

Comment: now it seems the file uploads as per the message but it is not attached to the email?

Comment: @Neo well it should be attached, but i get message that the file is empty, btw i get echo "file is valid and was succesfully uploaded"

Comment: can you paste the output of the var_dump that you have commented out?

Comment: var_dump just echoes array? kinda strange. does it not show file names?

Comment: @Neo whoops, you're right, i've dumped it in a wrong way, here's what it says  { ["error"]=> string(212) "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini." }

Comment: check the answer @user3670146 and try it once. The wp_handle_upload function returns an array whereas for mail attachments you just need the local file path.

Comment: ahh.. then it means the file does not upload correctly. Also check the answer for using the right way to use attachments. Can you check if the file being uploaded was not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
{ 
     require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['attachments'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
$attachments = $movefile;
if ( empty($movefile['error']) ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments['file']); 
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

`$attachments` returned is an array containing file, url and type. You need the file only for attachment.

Comment: did the trick with empty file, but i still get the following error but i still get the following error File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Could not access file: ' in /home/ad000min999/public_html/ogo/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:1971 Stack trace: #0 /home/ad000min999/public_html/ogo/wp-includes/pluggable.php(487): PHPMailer->addAttachment('') #1 /home/ad000min999/public_html/ogo/wp-content/themes/flatads/single.php(238): wp_mail('y

Comment: don't use empty files.

Comment: i don't use empty files, tried to upload txt,img and doc file and i get same error all the time

Comment: i don't remember now, but the thing that i remember is that i wrote enctype="multipart/form data" in the <input> line not in the <form> line, after i changed it, it was easy to debug and solve the attachment problem

Answer (score 0):

try to stop the script before you send email

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){

if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

                    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
                    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
                    if ( $movefile ) {
                        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                        var_dump($movefile);
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
                        exit();
                    }
                wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
        #$hasError = true;
}
```

and see if any error display

Comment: i found error for that, but i've got another one instead